# Replacing string using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have `.txt` file like this

The Catalog entry `"33102490"` - Catalog group `"1293"` 
Stack trace:

```
com.ibm.commerce.catalog.dataload.exception.CatalogDataLoadApplicationException: The Catalog entry "33102490" - Catalog group "1293" 
$1l.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:267)
```

I want only `"33102490"` and `"1293"` in the file. All other things need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*Catalog entry ("\d+").*Catalog group ("\d+").*$`
- Replace with: `$1\n$2`
- <kbd>Replace</kbd>

Make sure you have checked `Regular expression` and `. matches newline`